# constructing a mongo doc using pymodm from_document

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymodm

I am trying to construct a pymodm document from a python dictionary using from_document api. I am receiving a error "ValueError: Unrecognized field name 'prim_key'"

Here is the sample code that I have written to make this happen with minimum code.

```
from pymodm import connect, EmbeddedMongoModel, MongoModel, fields
from pymodm.errors import ValidationError, ConfigurationError
from pymongo.write_concern import WriteConcern
import pprint
from datetime import datetime

class sample_doc(MongoModel):
    prim_key = fields.CharField(primary_key=True)
    another_field = fields.CharField()

    class Meta:
        write_concern = WriteConcern(j=True)
        connection_alias = 'pymodm-tester'

connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/pymodm-tester", alias="pymodm-tester")

q = {'prim_key' : 'prim_val', "another_field" : "another_filed1" }
sample_doc.from_document(q).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](http://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html#pymodm.MongoModel.from_document):

> document: A Python dictionary describing a MongoDB document. Keys
>   within the document must be named according to each model field’s
>   mongo_name attribute, rather than the field’s Python name.

It looks that, in order to instantiate a Model as you try, it needs to be specified the `mongo_name` Field. It would work for you something like:

```
class sample_doc(MongoModel):
    prim_key = fields.CharField(primary_key=True, mongo_name="prim_key")
    another_field = fields.CharField(mongo_name="another_field")

    class Meta:
        write_concern = WriteConcern(j=True)
        connection_alias = 'pymodm-tester'
```